# git Mergetool - not able to choose which code to save

Tags: git, mergetool

I am in the git Mergetool. I am trying to select my local changes, and when I select the dropdown to choose left, nothing happens. Here is the screenshot

[image]

Is there something I am doing wrong? Why am I not able to have the mergetool actually choose the code?

Comment: it shows 5 conflicts. unless you resolve those you might not be able to merge.

Answer (score -1):

Just Save the file after you choose left and close it. You will be returned to the terminal for the next conflict.